# Accessing host port from virtualized guest system in Parallels 6 for Mac

Tags: windows-7, mac, networking, parallels

I have Windows 7 running in Parallels 6 on my iMac.

On my iMac, I have Tomcat running on port 8080.

How do I access Tomcat on my iMac (e.g. just using a Web browser) from Win7/Parallels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Bonjour installed on your Windows 7, you may try "host-name.local", i.e. the name listed in System Preferences -> Sharing.

If this doesn't work, you'll have to figure out the IP of the host in the virtual network. You might be able to find a "Parallels Shared Networking Adapter #0" in your Network preference panel. The IP address listed will be the one you want. If the adapter is not listed, run `ifconfig` from Terminal and look for the IP of "vnic0".

If there are multiple virtual adapters listed, open Parallel Desktop's preferences, go to Advanced and click Network : Change settings... In the dialogue click Shared and note the subnet. IP address belonging to that range should be the one you want to use. (Unless you setup the network differently.)

Comment: The adapter doesn't show up with `ipconfig` (I think that's what you meant). However, `hostname.local` in the browser URL bar worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for months! Thanks for posting!!